# Nested components and states in Vue with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am a Vue beginner and not sure how to handle nested components and states using Vuex.

Currently this is how I plan to add a new page called P to the project, initially it has one composite component, called C, and a button (let's call it B). Clicking B each time will add a new C to the page; apart from the very first C, others are deletable.

C uses a dropdown component (called D) and one of other three components (S, M and O) depending on what is selected from the dropdown D.

The first problem I have is that the D component has been designed so that its state is either managed directly on a store field or via a field on a state object. But here I could have one or many D components; how to manage its state in such a case using Vuex?
Just to add background, the D component is really just wrapping a label and a standard dropdown into a single component.

Comment: Do you really need to? UI state is more suitable to be handled in local states rather than global.

Comment: @EstusFlask I was thinking of trying that. D component is really just wrapping a label and a standard dropdown into a single component. I am not sure how to expose the dropdown value inside the D component to the C component.

Comment: Pass it through an event. As long as you don't need to interact between multiple comps with no straight parent-child relations, you don't need global store for this. It's common to use global store for business logic only, and local states are used for ui.